# Return non-consecutive cells from Sheet 1 in consecutive cells on Sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel 2013 Workbook with two Sheets. On Sheet 1, I have:

```
A1 = 1
B1 = 2
C1 = 3
D1 = 4
...
Z1 = 26
```

In other words, it's 1, 2, 3...26 across the top row.

On Sheet 2, I want:

```
A1 = Sheet1!J1
B1 = Sheet1!O1
C1 = Sheet1!T1
etc.
```

In other words, on Sheet2, I want A1 to show the data on Sheet1!J1, then I want B1 to return five columns to the right from Sheet1!J1.

Finally, I want to be able to repeat that pattern on Sheet2 all across the top row (hopefully by dragging across).

Comment: Your request is not clear. How is your data actually laid out? So far I can see that this would be easiest enough to do by manually typing in your formula on Sheet2 3 more times. Is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sheet!A1 use this formula,

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!1:1, 1, (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*5+10)
```

Fill right as necessary.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, In your formula above, what does the "-1" do?

Comment: Select A1 and use the [Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) command. Repeat if necessary until you understand it. Next, select B1 and repeat the process. The purpose of the (-1) should be immediately apparent.